# htaccess with specific folder exception

Tags: .htaccess, exception, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've set up an htaccess file in order to create a small routing structure where urls redirect to index.php. I want to add an exception where if the user types in "/admin" and anything after, the url instead redirects to admin.php.

htaccess -

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^admin/?(.*)$ admin.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Example: http://mysite.com/admin/settings/ should lead to admin.php?page=settings, while http://mysite.com/about/ should lead to index.php (not using any parameters here). Regexp is  really not my cup of tea, especially when there are multiple conditions to consider. Ideas?

Edit: ^admin/([^/]*)/? solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this in one .htaccess file in root directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   !admin\.php    [NC]
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/]*)/? /admin.php?page=$1  [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !/admin/        [NC]
RewriteRule .*              /index.php      [NC,L]
```

For permanent redirection, replace [NC],L] with [R=301,NC,L]

Comment: Using ^admin/([^/]*)/? did the trick. Thanks. I still haven't exactly grasped when to use NC and L. I still only use L for the admin.php rewrite and it seems to work fine.

Comment: You are welcome. *Use of the [NC] flag causes the RewriteRule to be matched in a case-insensitive manner.*. So it is important to use it. Check this [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_nc) for more info.